# User with all questions deleted (and no answers) is blocked from answering but not asking

Tags: support, asking-questions, deleted-questions, post-ban

On Android we recently suspended a user for asking 6 low quality and off topic questions, with no other contribution at all.  All those questions have been flagged and deleted, and some were closed, and yet the user is blocked from **answering** but not from **asking** (not even limited).  You'd think that it would be both, or reversed.  Is something wonky here?

The user in question: https://android.stackexchange.com/users/107594/vassiaalk

```
blocked from asking             no
blocked from answering          yes
limited to 1 question per week  no
```

Comment: It looks evil to suspend a user and then discuss their suspension publically on Meta with link to profile and stats (whose visibility should have been confined to mods).

Comment: The suspension notice and his questions are more than enough to derive all the info I have here (other than what surprised me here, which is *less* blockage than expected). I wouldn't include any private info from our mod messages.

Comment: I should add that if you feel strongly about it, please flag this post and we'll see what other mods/employees think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The indefinite (sometimes known as "comprehensive") question block isn't enabled on Android; there's [a rate-limiter](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited), but due to a peculiar rounding behavior it thinks this particular user has an average question score of 0 and isn't kicking in.

The answer block however, is enabled *everywhere*. And it sees nothing but **a huge pile of deleted posts**. That's generally *bad news*, so it kicks in. This is useful behavior; users with nothing but deleted posts generally do not write useful answers, regardless of the nature of those deleted posts.

Comment: Hmm, so essentially by dealing with the posts before they accrue many downvotes we're preventing the system from kicking in?  Time to moderate less!  (Kidding.)  Good to know that the question block isn't turned on for us, though.  Is it just SO, or larger sites generally?  (I definitely agree that this is useful -- that's why I expected the block to be for both.)

Comment: You can always down vote before you delete... Heck, a VLQ flag wouldn't be amiss on some of these. Hint.